# isset() on the result of an expression

Tags: php

I have this `isset()` below because I want to show an empty string if the result of `$this->field($content, 'description')` is null.

However doing like this it shows

> Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression

Do you know how to properly achieve this?

```php
return [
    'description' => isset($this->field($content, 'description') ? $this->field($content, 'description') : '',
    //...
];
```

Comment: Save the expressions result to a variable and pass that to `isset()`. See the 'warning' part on the docs page: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php#refsect1-function.isset-notes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use the null coalescing operator `??` (https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.coalesce)

```
return [
    'description' => $this->field($content, 'description') ?? '',
    //...
];
```

Comment: Like that it shows "Argument #1 ($content) must be of type array, null given, but it strange doing for example only like this works: "    'description' => '',
". Do you know what can be the issue? Thanks

Comment: @Ozzdev *only like this works: `" 'description' => '', ".`*, we would need to see your code that is processing the return value of your code-snippet but that would be a separate question. If resolving one issue exposes another, it is not fair to those providing the initial resolution to keep raising the bar and altering the original question with a new issue.

Comment: @WillB. nice catch, I added the ellipsis from the OP without thinking.

Answer (score 1):

You can use php ternary operator `?:`

```
return [
    'description' => $this->field($content, 'description') ?: '',
    //...
];
```

Comment: Please keep in mind that this will match on all falsey values such as `0, false, "0", [], null`, as opposed to explicitly `null`.